# Does $xy > xz$ imply $y > z$?

Tags: inequality

$xy > xz$

We don't know the sign of $x$.

Can we conclude $y>z$ from above?

Comment: No (Try some examples).

Comment: How about $x=-1$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because if $x<0$ then we have
$$xy>xz\implies y<z$$
as the direction of the inequality changes when multiplied by a negative number.
If x is on the other hand positive we have
$$xy>xz\implies y>z$$
as the inequality remains

Very simple example is $x=-1$